# What is the correct way to retrieve data from 2 or more identical components?

Tags: vue.js

Evening. I've created a button which adds a component that has an input field inside. I might need to press that button few times so there would be 2-3 input fields that appear. Whenever I type the text I would like to send a request from the parent component but I don't know how to retrieve the data from every child component that has been created. Is this the time to start using vuex (never used it)?

```
ParentComponent.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" @click="addStep">Add step</button>
        <div v-for="i in count">
            <recipe-step v-bind:step-number="i"></recipe-step>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                count: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addStep() {
                this.count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

StepComponent.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="step-input"></label>
            <input id="step-input" v-model="text" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            stepNumber: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                step: this.stepNumber,
                text: ""
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you really don't need Vuex yet. As long as you are still dealing with parent-child-component communication, you should be fine. Vuex comes into play when components, spread across the hole component hierarchy, need to exchange information.

Now, you should do something like this:

Don't store the `text` in the child component. When the input changes, send a *Custom Event* right to the parent component. Note that

`<input v-model="text">`

is only syntax sugar for

`<input :value="text" @input="text = $event">`

Both have the same effect. That's way you can send the input event up to the parent, like this:

`<input @input="$emit('input', $event)">`

Add another prop to your child component called `value` which should replace `text`.

And now you can use `v-model` in the parent component:

`<recipe-step v-model="text">`

To store multiple values, just use an array in your data properties.

`<recipe-step v-model="textArray[i]">`

Answer (score 0):

Vuex can help you on that, however if all you want is to get the input text value back to the parent with the minimum effort you can create a prop called value in the children and then pass it as v-model in the parent.

Since you have a v-for you could make it iterate over a list instead a counter and then pass some prop inside each item as v-model

Comment: thanks for reply. Passing v-model from children component to parent would mean using eventbus, emit or I didn't understand this correctly?